# Aptana "Content Assist" did not complete normally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aptana

I have a problem with the Aptana Studio 3.

It is a fresh installation. I have imported a Ruby on Rails - project that a edited with a texteditor before. I want to use Aptana, for a more comfortable development but the Content Assist fails.

If I try to use the Content Assist it throws the following exception and write it to the Console:

```
[2013-03-08 16:34:40] An error occurred while processing the invoke block for the command ERb Content Assist in C:\Users\Chris\Aptana Rubles\rails.ruble\commands\content_assist.rb: (NoMethodError) undefined method `getInstance' for Java::ComAptanaIndexCore::IndexManager:Class
org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (NoMethodError) undefined method `getInstance' for Java::ComAptanaIndexCore::IndexManager:Class
    at Rails::ContentAssistant.index_manager(C:/Users/Chris/Aptana Rubles/rails.ruble/lib/content_assistant.rb:87)
    at Rails::ContentAssistant.gem_indices(C:/Users/Chris/Aptana Rubles/rails.ruble/lib/content_assistant.rb:79)
    at org.jruby.RubyProc.call(org/jruby/RubyProc.java:274)
    at org.jruby.RubyProc.call(org/jruby/RubyProc.java:229)
    at Java::JavaUtil::Collection.each(C:/Users/Chris/AppData/Local/Aptana Studio 3/plugins/org.jruby_1.6.4.1331328108/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared/builtin/java/java.util.rb:7)
    at org.jruby.RubyEnumerable.collect(org/jruby/RubyEnumerable.java:706)
    at Rails::ContentAssistant.gem_indices(C:/Users/Chris/Aptana Rubles/rails.ruble/lib/content_assistant.rb:79)
at Rails::ContentAssistant.gem_and_project_indices(C:/Users/Chris/Aptana Rubles/rails.ruble/lib/content_assistant.rb:74)
at Rails::ContentAssistant.assist(C:/Users/Chris/Aptana Rubles/rails.ruble/lib/content_assistant.rb:31)
at #<Class:0x101f95cf6>.define_content_assist(C:\Users\Chris\Aptana Rubles\rails.ruble\commands\content_assist.rb:7)
at org.jruby.RubyProc.call(org/jruby/RubyProc.java:274)
at org.jruby.RubyProc.call(org/jruby/RubyProc.java:233)
```

The Aptana Log File contains this message:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2013-03-08 16:34:40.465
!MESSAGE "Content Assist" did not complete normally.  Please see the log for more information.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2013-03-08 16:34:40.465
!MESSAGE (Errno::EINVAL) =::
!STACK 0
org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (Errno::EINVAL) =::
    at org.jruby.RubyHash.replace(org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1623)
```

I don't know how to handle this error. Do I have to install anything else to use the Content Assist with Ruby on Rails?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution at https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-2718

> As a workaround:
>
> 1) Commands > Rails Bundle > Edit this Bundle will grab a copy of the
>   new code

This removed the error messages for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this link, that describes my problem as "Unresolved" (reported in 12/Sep/12):

https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-7406

But this is "Aptana Studio 3.2.2" and I have got Version 3.3.3, I can't believe that this problem isn't solved.

Anybody else using Aptana knowing this problem?